# fopen is not working on elastic beanstalk php

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using the following code in elastic beanstalk php to generate log file but I am getting this error.But the same code is working on another server. How can I make it work ?

Error:

```
Error opening file in write mode!
```

Code  :

```
$path="/var/www/html/aws";
$fileName =$path.'/logs/data'.date('Y-m-d_H-i-s'). '_' . uniqid() . '.txt';
$file = fopen($fileName,'w') or die('Could not create report file: ' . $fileName);
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $reportLine = $key." = ".$value."\n";
    fwrite($file, $reportLine) or die ('Could not write to report file ' . $reportLine);
}

fputs($file,"log aws");
fclose($file);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your `php` user `www-data` have permission to write in `$path.'/logs/` folder or just `chmod` that `logs` folder to `0777` permisson